# C programming Char possible values

Tags: c, char

I am trying to learn C and now I am learning chars. I have read some where that char can be signed and unsigned. This part I get but when I use an unsigned char(which I thought could held value 0-255)

```
printf("%c", 400);
```

or even

```
printf("%c\n", (unsigned char)400);
```

it prints out an `É`

Why is this?

Comment: Somebody allready posted his answere which was partial right! It prints out 144 because 400 % 256 is 144 which is an É. So thank you whoever you was!

Comment: You should also learn how to inspect your program in a debugger. It would show you exactly what `(unsigned char)400` does. (In this case you are also making the assumption that `printf` does what you want it to, running in a debugger would avoid that trap as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned char c = 400;
printf("%d",c);
```

Guess what, you will get `144` printed. That's because an **overflow** occurred in `c`.

An `unsigned char` takes exactly 8 bits of memory (on almost every platform), so that it's a variable in the range of **00000000**(0) ~ **11111111**(255). Whenever you try to assign a number which is more than 8 bits in binary to an unsigned char, **the left superfluous bits will overflow and lost**.

In your case, you tried to assign 400 to an unsigned char:

400 = **110010000** which has 9 bits, so **the highest 1 will lost**, then you got **10010000** actually assigned to the char, which is 144 in decimal.

When you print it as `%d`, you will get `144`; When you print it as `%c`, you will get `É` which is the 144th character in the [Extended ASCII Codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) (in your case).

Comment: @MouNtant OK. I am glad to be of help:-)

Comment: _"`unsigned char` takes exactly 8 bits"_ no, though that's true on almost every platform, even in the OP's one. Also I think it's worth mentioning that the result is implementation defined.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), when `c` format specifier is provided to `printf` with no `l` length modiﬁer,

> the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

This means that 400 is converted to an `unsigned char`, which is `400 % 256`, or `144`. Then, the character that corresponds to `144` is written out. This is a [*UNICODE control sequence*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0090/index.htm), so that `É` character that you see is system-dependent.

Comment: @Skyler It depends. On a system with a latin1 locale, it will (almost certainly, it could be that the implementation uses a different execution character set) print the letter `É`. On my box with a UTF-8 locale, it prints `�` a control character.